# Detect when Ctrl is pressed

Tags: gtk, vala

I'm implementing a ctrl+click solution for links in a textview and am having trouble setting the cursor to a hand when Ctrl is being held. Right now I

1. set the cursor to a hand in mouse motion when mouse moves inside the textview and control is pressed and the mouse is on top of a link (I use TextTag to style the links, so I just check whether the text below the mouse has this tag.).
2. set the mouse cursor back to the text edit cursor otherwise

However, when the mouse is on top of the link and I press Ctrl (without moving the mouse) the cursor does not change. Clearly, no mouse motion was detected so this is the expected behavior. My problem is how to implement this. I tried adding a `keypress` handler to the textview, but

1. it only fires when the textview has focus. This is not always the case, since I might not click the textview before clicking the link.
2. `event.get_state()` only comes with `CONTROL_MASK` if other key is pressed as well.
3. I receive no information about the mouse cursor, so I end up not knowing where it is pointing inside the `keypress` handler.

How can I solve these issues so I can have a Ctrl+click solution that shows adequate cursor when Ctrl is being pressed? I can already solve it by considering only mouse motion. The problem is how to detect Ctrl being pressed and react accordingly without mouse motion.